# multiple columns on x axis after a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, visualization

I have the following code that works well :

```
df.groupby(['State', 'City']).Total_sale_amount.sum().plot.bar()
```

I want the equivalent to use on a dataframe i got after doing a groupby on that same dataframe with this code :

```
df_city_sales = df.groupby(['City','State']).agg(Total_sale_amount=('Total_sale_amount', 'sum')
).reset_index()
```

Now when i try to plot this new dataframe with a code like this :

```
plt.bar(df_city_sales[['City', 'State']], df_city_sales['Total_sale_amount'])
```

It doesn't work, i tried other syntaxes but it doesn't work, what is the equivalent to get a plot like this ? Thanks.

[image]

Other syntaxes like

```
plt.bar([df_city_sales['City'], df_city_sales['State']], df_city_sales['Total_sale_amount'])
```

or

```
plt.bar((df_city_sales['City'], df_city_sales['State']), df_city_sales['Total_sale_amount'])
```

have been tried, without success.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work", what output do you get?

Comment: @sdawar i get various errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution :

```
cities_states = df_city_sales['City'].str.cat(df_city_sales['State'], sep=', ') 

plt.bar(cities_states, df_city_sales['Total_sale_amount'])
```

[image]